# Permission denied when trying to write into log file

Tags: c, windows, file, permissions, fopen

I have a problem writing into a log file in my C/C++ prog.
Here's an example of the code where the problem occurs

```
EnterCriticalSection(&critical);
printf("\nWaiting for a connection on TCP port %d (nbr of current threads = %d)...\n", pServer->TCPServerPort, (*pServer->lChildInfo));
AddLog("Waiting for a connection on TCP port %d (nbr of current threads = %d)...", pServer->TCPServerPort, (*pServer->lChildInfo));
LeaveCriticalSection(&critical);

// creating variables to be passed to the thread
struct*ThreadData = (struct*) malloc(sizeof(struct));
ThreadData->csock = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
memcpy(&ThreadData->pServer,&pServer,sizeof(pServer));

if((*ThreadData->csock = accept( pServer->ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&sadr, &addr_size))!= INVALID_SOCKET ){

    ThreadData->dwIP = sadr.sin_addr.s_addr;
    ThreadData->wPort = sadr.sin_port;

    printf("Received connection from %s:%d \n",inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr), ntohs(sadr.sin_port));
    AddLog("Received connection from %s:%d ",inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr), ntohs(sadr.sin_port));
```

AddLog is the function i wrote in order to write into the file :

```
FILE *fichier = NULL;
va_list ap;
va_start(ap, log); 
//fichier = fopen("log.log","a");
fichier = _fsopen("log.log", "a", SH_DENYNO);
if (fichier == NULL)  
    printf("Error log: %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
else {  
    fprintf(fichier,":");
    vfprintf(fichier, log, ap);
    fprintf(fichier,"\n");
    va_end(ap);
    fclose(fichier);    
}
```

What I can't really explain is that the first AddLog ("Waiting for...." and all the ones before..) are correctly written into the file. But when i try a connection, the logs coming then (received connection from...) are not written into the file and i always get the error 13 "Permission denied".
I used chmod 777 into the file, i also tried _fsopen function and i still get this error once i enter into the thread.
If someone have any idea it would be reaaally helpful.
Thanks to all

Comment: show us the complete sample program and it may help find the problem.

Comment: Since your initial `AddLog()` call is guarded by a critical section, I suspect all other instances should be as well. Not sure if that's your problem or not, but it is *a* problem. Also, you probably should move the `va_start()` in `AddLog()` inside the `else` clause, as otherwise the matching `va_end()` may never get called - whether that's a problem may be implementation-dependent, though...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if it the problem , But i would suggest using "a+" inside _fsopen
for shared append because thread another process.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is still relevant , but I have to suggest you to use a bit better solution:
(I encountered the same problem few days ago and the solution was more than trivial)
I just implemented a shared queue and all the logs I added in to the queue afterwards I run a worker thread that was checking the queue and was writing to the file if the queue wasn't empty.

I hope it helped have a nice day :)